# Show/hide menu based on condition for fragment

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

i have one fragment that displays list with help of adapter.in list there is a link click in which user calls another activity that calls an adapter to get data .After getting data we can add ata and save in that adapter this directs user to fragment 1 to save data .

.initially I don't want menu as save in fragment1. Once the user add data in onclick of the list which opens another list to add data and returns to fragment1 then I need to display menu save.....I have tried.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_save, menu);
    shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save1);
    shareItem.setVisible(false);

}
```

Later based on condition I am doing:   `shareItem.setVisible(true);`

Comment: And what you got?

Comment: does that anotherList return some value to your fragment1 ??

Comment: yes it returns object

Answer (score 1):

As you are starting another activity for result, you can use `startActivityForResult()`. After getting the data, you can enable the menu. 
Here you can get more information [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

For an example, when you start activity set the result code for example 1. Then after getting the activity data, finish the second activity like this way

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And in your `onActivityResult` you can check if the result ok then enable your menu.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
               //data is updated. 
             myitem.setvisiblity(true)
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am using this method only on activity result i am checking like id data added!=0 means then setvisibity(true); but not working

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and hide the item based on your condition

```
 @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_save1);
    item.setVisible(false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Also make sure you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()`

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))

> `boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)` Prepare the Screen's standard
>   options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is
>   shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently
>   enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean variable as field in activity `isShareItemVisible = true`, then when conditions are changed set it to `false` and call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`. In the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method use this variable, i.e.:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_save, menu);
    shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save1);
    shareItem.setVisible(isShareItemVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before opening another list you can set a boolean value to true and when you get back to the fragment1 again `setUserVisibleHint()` method will be called and you can check that boolean value and `isVisibleToUser` variable value. If both of them are true then you can visible the menu item.

```
@Override  
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

Or If you are opening another activity for getting data you can use `startActivityForResult()` method. When you sends back the data to Activity. It's `onActivityResult()` will be called. From where you can check the `requestCode` and all your fragments `startActivityForResult()` method. From where you can set the menu item.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
            Fragment fragment1 = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (fragment1 != null) {
                fragment1 .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am starting activity using startactivity for reult there i am saying like myitem.setvisiblity(true); but not worked.

Comment: are you setting visibility from `onActivityResult()` method?

Comment: yes   if (nestedhashmap.linkgarmentdata!=null) {
                  shareItem.setVisible(true);

Comment: check if `nestedhashmap.linkgarmentdata` null ? can you share your code of `onActivityResult()` method?

Comment: no it is not null i am getting size as 1 if i debug.